# How to access a class variable from the outside in ruby?

Tags: ruby, class-variables

I'm trying to access a class variable from a method outside of the class.

This is my class:

```
class Book

  @@bookCount = 0
  @@allBooks = []

  def self.allBooks
    @@allBooks
  end

  def self.bookCount
    @@bookCount
  end

  attr_accessor :name,:author,:date,:genre,:rating

  def initialize(name, author, date, genre, rating)
      @name = name
      @author = author
      @date = date
      @genre = genre
      @rating = rating
      @@bookCount += 1
      @@allBooks << self
  end

end
```

This is the method trying to access the class variable @@bookCount

```
def seeBookShelf
  if @@bookCount == 0
    puts "Your bookshelf is empty."
  else
    puts "You have " + @bookCount + " books in your bookshelf:"
    puts allBooks
  end
end
```

When I try to execute the method I get this:

```
undefined local variable or method `bookCount' for main:Object (NameError)
```

How can I access bookCount from the outside?

Comment: First question: Why are you using class variables? These share information between the class and instances in a way that often leads to a confusion of concerns. `self.class.allBooks` is better than directly accessing it.

Comment: Ruby conventions also strongly recommend that you name things in the style of `see_book_shelf` with no capitals in variables or method names. Classes have mixed case, leading capital, like you have here.

Comment: Due to the way this retains references of any Book instance created this is basically asking for memory problems. You'd be better off creating a BookShelf class that's specifically intended to store books rather than delegating this responsibility to the Book's class level.

Comment: Perhaps define `VARIABLE = @@book_count` in the Book class, then use `Book::VARIABLE` outside of the class. But not sure if this is a recommended technique, so be wary.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Sharing constants is also a messy business. It's better to have a thin layer of intermediation via a method call so that way you have some isolation and the method's implementation can change without breaking tons of stuff.

Comment: **Reader challenge**: How could you do this if there were no getter method for `@@bookCount` and you were not permitted to use the method [Module#class_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_get)?

Answer (score 15):

Use `class_variable_get` to access a class variable outside of a class:

```
class Foo
  @@a = 1
end

Foo.class_variable_get(:@@a)
=> 1
```

Comment: Technically correct, but also ill-advised. The `class_variable_get` method is intended for reflection purposes, not general purpose programming.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`class_eval`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/class_eval) to evaluate a block of code within the scope of a specific class:

```
class Book
  @@bookCount = 1
end

Book.class_eval '@@bookCount'
# => 1
```

And just for fun... you can actually do all kinds of trickery with `class_eval` such as define a new method in the class without monkey patching:

```
Book.class_eval { @@bookCount = 5 }
Book.class_eval '@@bookCount'
# => 5

Book.class_eval do
  def self.hey_look_a_new_method
    return "wow"
  end
end

Book.hey_look_a_new_method
# => "wow"
```

Answer (score 3):

For most cases, class instance variables are preferred to class variables. The latter are prone to all manner of strange behaviour when used with inheritance.

Consider:

```
class Book
  @book_count = 0
  @all_books = []

  class << self
    attr_reader :book_count
    attr_reader :all_books
  end

  # further code omitted.

end
```

With this code Book.book_count and Book.all_books get the expected data.

Answer (score 1):

You need a getter to access the class variable, try this code.
See http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/ for an explanation.
You are also better to use string interpolation otherwise you get a Type error, also it is more Rubyesque.

```
class Book
  @@bookCount = 0

  def self.bookCount
    @@bookCount
  end
end

def seeBookShelf
  if Book.bookCount == 0
    puts "Your bookshelf is empty."
  else
    puts "You have #{Book.bookCount} books in your bookshelf:"
  end
end

seeBookShelf # Your bookshelf is empty.
```

Comment: almost the same answer as @Gregory did.

Comment: Yeah, we were aswering at the same time, I like to try my answers and publish them as a whole runnable piece, often then I'm beaten by someone faster, I think our solution is better than Ilya's, have you tried them ? noticed the error when bookcount > 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the Class of the variable :

```
def seeBookShelf
  if Book.bookCount == 0
    puts "Your bookshelf is empty."
  else
    puts "You have " + Book.bookCount + " books in your bookshelf:"
    puts Book.allBooks
  end
end
```

Comment: Still, directly accessing variables is a bad way of doing it. You should add getters in your class. Or create a new class BookShelf to store all your book.

Comment: `self.class` also works here if this is in an instance method.