# how to change instance variables in class in ruby

Tags: ruby, instance

I have some legacy code and completely new to Ruby. I want to change the value of a class instance in Ruby.

```
class CoffeeMachine
  attr_reader :water
  def initialize
    @water = 100
  end
end
machine = CoffeeMachine.new
machine.water
```

I now want to change `machine.water` to 70. I learned that these instances are protected through something called "Encapsulation". But I'm wondering if there is not any way to change this variable. Following [this](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/class_eval) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027031/how-to-access-a-class-variable-from-the-outside-in-ruby/41029946) I tried changing it like so:

`machine.class_eval {@water = 70}`

but it doesn't work. When I print it out like so

`puts machine.class_eval '@water'` it shows 70 but when I use it in my program it somehow doesn't get stored.

Comment: Why not use the [`attr_accessor :water`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor)?

Comment: However this violates encapsulation, you can do: `machine.instance_variable_set(:"@water", 70)` to set the instance variable's value. Although I'd recommend using the `attr_accessor` as it gives you both getter and setter methods.

Comment: ahhhhhh, kk thanks ! I'm such an idiot, works

Comment: @Tom : I guess you mean that you want to change the value of an **instance variable**, and not the value of an **instance**. Why do you declare `water` explicitly as _unchangeable from outside_, if you then want to change it? This does not make sense.

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry ! I thought the question is so noob, it's not even worth asking, I unaccepted the answer again to wait for more, sry again

Comment: @user1934428 sorry, I'm very new to Ruby, I didn't know I explicitly set it as unchangeable, how did I do that? By not declaring `attr_accessor`?

Comment: With `attr_reader`, you only specify that you can read the environment variable. Basically, it generates an accessor method for this variable. Similarily, `attr_writer` creates a setter method for the variable. `attr_accessor` creates both. See [here](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/attr_accessor/).

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `machine.instance_eval { @water=70 }`. Note that `class_eval` would allow for variables on class scope, while `instance_eval`, as the name implies, can be used for fiddling with instance variables. Of course, you will avoid both if possible, since their use breaks the idea of encapsulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Scenario this will be more convenient way to Handle it

```
class CoffeeMachine
  attr_reader :water
  def initialize(water=100)
    @water = water
  end
end
```

```
machine = CoffeeMachine.new

machine.water # 100

machine = CoffeeMachine.new(70)

machine.water # 70
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Surya suggested it's also possible to do:

```
    class CoffeeMachine
      attr_accessor :water
      def initialize
        @water = 100
      end
    end
```

and then do this:

```
   machine = CoffeeMachine.new
   machine.water #100
 
   machine.water = 70
   machine.water #70
```

Comment: we not need to use the `attr_reader` if we are using the `attr_accessor` because it work for both set and get.